# Javascript Reflection - Get properties of a JsonResult object

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reflection, jsonresult

I have a object that returned from `JsonResult`
I want to get all properties of object in client, like C# Reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var property in object){
 if(object.hasOwnProperty(property)){//prevents from getting inherent properties
   console.log(object[property])
 }
}
```